# Ansible - How to have domain group as a variable

Tags: windows, variables, ansible

I am trying to place some variable in a playbook I have, save repeating them over and over.

The type of variable I am having issues with relates to the win_acl and win_share modules. I want to set variable something like this;

```
vars:
     users_group_a: domain\user_group_a
```

Then use it in the playbook

```
win_acl:
       path: x:\y\z
       user: "{{ users_group_a }}"
```

But I am getting errors that account name domain\user_group_a is not a valid account and identify cannot be translated - but if I put this in myself it works fine. Does the \ need to be escaped when using it in variables??

Thanks
Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked it out, just needed to remove the spaces calling the variable so;

```
"{{ users_group_a }}"
```

Turns into

```
"{{users_group_a}}"
```

Seems to have made a difference